# Transparent Data Encryption for Large DataBase

Tags: sql, encryption, tde

I am using large database for my application and i have encrypted the database using TDE method. It is taking more time to encrypt. How long need to encrypt the large database? Can we access the DB to insert/retrieve data while encryption is in progress?

Comment: The question is too broad. Consider providing a [MCVE]

Comment: What makes you think it is taking more time to encrypt? If you have a performance issue, you need to isolate what it really is.

Answer (score 1):

You can benchmark how long the encryption takes with this query:

```
declare @pct float;
select @pct = e.percent_complete from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys e, 
    sys.databases d where e.database_id = d.database_id and d.name = 'mydb';
select @pct 'percent';
```